# Does ArrayList.get() return the same thing as array[]?

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

In Processing, I have an ArrayList of objects built from a custom class. When I use the `.get()` function to return one of the objects, it seems to return the object all right -- but I can't access any of the object's variables or methods. I get the error message "[variable] cannot be resolved or is not a field." Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's a sample. Notice the values returned from the `setup()` function.

```
// regular array
Thing[] thinglist1 = new Thing[1];

// ArrayList array
ArrayList thinglist2 = new ArrayList<Thing>(1);

// instantiate the class
Thing thing = new Thing(12345);

// class definition
class Thing {
  int var;

  Thing(int i){
    var = i;
    thinglist1[0] = this;
    thinglist2.add(this);
  };
};

// run it!
void setup(){
  println(thinglist1[0] == thinglist2.get(0));
  // true

  println(thinglist1[0].var);
  // 12345

  println(thinglist2.get(0).var);
  // ERROR: "var cannot be resolved or is not a field"
};
```

Comment: related: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've kinda messed up your generics.

Change

```
ArrayList thinglist2 = new ArrayList<Thing>(1);
```

to:

```
ArrayList<Thing> thinglist2 = new ArrayList<Thing>(1);
```

Because you didn't specify a type, what you really had was:

```
ArrayList<? extends Object> thinglist2 = new ArrayList<Thing>(1);
```

So when you retrieved an item from it using `get`, it was typed as `Object` rather than your `Thing`

**Edit to add**: The reason for this is legacy; when generics were introduced things were put in place for backward compatibility.  Unfortunately that creates situations like this which is confusing to someone new to Java.

You'd prob expect a compiler warning or error, but Java silently changes that non-generic-typed `ArrayList` into "Arraylist that contains something that extends Object" ... which is anything (except a primitive), because all objects implicitly extend `Object`

Comment: I would just say "what you really had was: `ArrayList<Object>` ..." - since it's more accurate and adding wildcards to the mix could be confusing.

Comment: @PaulBellora - already fixed that in an edit - refresh ;) I think stating what's really happening is more accurate, and then explaining why.

Comment: Right, I'm saying I would change it back.

Comment: I understand your point, I just disagree that posting something incorrect is "more accurate". "Easier to understand" perhaps, but certainly not accurate.

Answer (score -2):

In the last line you must cast return value from get function to the array of object.

```
System.out.println(((Thing[])thinglist2.get(0))[0].var);
```